# System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductVersion produces FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, winforms

Can anyone explain how `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductVersion` can throw a `FileNotFoundException`?

Stack trace is

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
 at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(System.String)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Application.GetAppFileVersionInfo()
 at System.Windows.Forms.Application.get_ProductVersion()
```

The error only affects one user and is inconsistent, but when it occurs, it is when the application is starting up, so the exe must exist for the application to start.

The exe resides on a network share, but there is no evidence of any network or disk errors.

What is also strange is that the program sets up UnHandledException and ThreadException  handlers to log all such errors and these routines are not being called.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check if the user has any difference in permissions from other working users?

Comment: The user has full control of the network share. Also the error is inconsistent and sometimes works and sometime doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a latency observed in accessing the network share location. You can first check if the file exists at that location and then get the version, to avoid this.

Comment: How file can not exist, if it's a file being runned?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, I know, as the exception is FileNotFound, the OS is trying to locate the file on the network share and is getting some latency. To avoid that we can do the file exist check.

Comment: Stack track shows it is calling GetVersionInfo which according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo.aspx takes a file name as a parameter. Given that this is a public method and can take anything as a parameter, it is almost certainly **already** calling File.Exists and presumably this is failing and throwing the exception (Question is why).

Comment: As we have the .Net Source code, we can look at it :) Have a look at [FileVersioInfo.cs](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Services/Monitoring/system/Diagnosticts/FileVersionInfo@cs/1305376/FileVersionInfo@cs) . In the method GetVersionInfo, it does check if the file exists ofcourse, and if it  returns false (read permission is denied), It tries to get the full path and requests read access, and if this does not throw an exception, then throws the FileNotFoundException. So, it looks like the cause is a path discovery issue.